# DataValueField Missing in kendo Autocomplete

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

I am using kendo autocomplete control in my MVC project(Server side filtering).It list the data correctly. But the problem is when i submit the data to server the autocomplete value id is missing. Because there is no DataValueField attribute in this control. The bellow code is i am using

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
    .Name("Patient")
    .Placeholder("Enter Name")
    .DataTextField("TextField")
    .Filter("contains")
    .MinLength(3)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
      source.Read(read =>
      {
         read.Action("function", "controller")
         .Data("onAdditionalData");
      })
         .ServerFiltering(true);
  })
)
```

How can i send the value to the server.

Thank you..

Comment: is there a `DataValue` property you can use?

Comment: thanks for your response JohnB. There is no property called DataValue

Comment: ok - or field with a similar name that would hold the `Value` eg ID of the thing your dropdown is binding to...?

Comment: I think you can use a hidden field for passing the value from autocomplete helper. Just additional `HiddenFor` combined with select event should enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `AutoComplete` helper doesn't have `DataValueField` attribute, you need to use other HTML helper as workaround to pass another property value. Suppose your viewmodel has this setup:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    // ID property example
    public int PatientID { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

You can create a hidden field or read-only textbox to store ID property mentioned above inside Razor view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PatientID)
```

Then, assign its `value` attribute from client-side script by creating a function which reads item index from autocomplete helper:

```
function selectPatient(e) {
    var item = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
    $('#PatientID').val(item.PatientID);
}
```

And finally set the function name bound for `Events` attribute:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
    .Name("Patient")
    .Placeholder("Enter Name")
    .DataTextField("TextField")
    .Filter("contains")
    .MinLength(3)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })

    // add this line
    .Events(ev => ev.Select("selectPatient"))

    .DataSource(source => {
        source.Read(read => {
            read.Action("function", "controller")
            .Data("onAdditionalData");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
)
```

By following this setup, the `PatientID` property should have ID of the selected value from autocomplete helper when user submitted the form.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of the `AutoComplete` widget.  One way around it is to add an attribute via a template to store the data value on the control:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
    .Name("Patient")
    .Placeholder("Enter Name")
    .DataTextField("TextField")
    .Filter("contains")
    .MinLength(3)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("function", "controller").Data("onAdditionalData");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .Events(events => events.Select("onPatientSelected"))
    .Template("<span data-recordid=\"#= data.ID #\"> #: data.ID # &ndash; #: data.Name #</span>")
)
```

This assumes `ID` and `Name` are properties of the patient object.

Then you can handle the `Select` event to get the stored ID value when a selection is made:

```
function onPatientSelected(arg) {
    var selectedPatientID = arg.item.find('span').data('recordid')

    // do whatever with the ID, such as sending it to the server
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the dataItem in javascript, and then access the value property.
If you call `myKendoAutoCompleteControl.dataItem()` it will give you the currently selected item as an array of key/value pairs.

```
$("#myKendoAutoCompleteId").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "Text",
    dataValueField: "Value",
    dataSource: mydatasource,
    filter: "startswith",
    placeholder: "Search..."
    //separator: ", "
});

var  myKendoAutoCompleteControl = 
$("#myKendoAutoCompleteId").data("kendoAutoComplete");

// once user has selected an item in the kendo auto complete control, you 
can access the selected item.
var dataItemArray = myKendoAutoCompleteControl.dataItem();
var value = dataItemArray.Value
```

Comment: Update: This doesn't seem to work when using server side filtering. As a workaround, I had to store the currently selected item using select function for the control.